# Redux toolkit not updating array of array object

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I'm trying to update an object that is nested in an array of arrays.

```
state = [[{away: "Southampton "
awayTeamScore: null
date: "Sat, October 30th 2021"
dateNative: "2021-10-30T14:00:00Z"
home: "Watford "
homeTeamScore: null
matchId: 327264
matchday: 10
score: "null - null"
time: "16:00"
winner: null}, {..etc}], [{..etc}]]
```

I am passing my payload which looks like this:

```
{matchId: 327264
score: 1
team: "awayTeamScore"}
```

But my redux state does not update, I tried to follow the official docs regaring immer etc.

My attempt reducer, using createSlice:

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const predictFormSlice: any = createSlice({
    name: "predictForm",
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        SAVE_FIXTURES: (state: any, action) => {
            state.push(action.payload);
        },
        UPDATE_PREDICTIONS: (state: any, action) => {
            state = state[0].map((element: any[]) => {
                let game = element.find((game: { matchId: any }) => game.matchId === action.payload.matchId);

                if (game) {
                    game = action.payload;
                }
            });
        },
    },
});

export const { SAVE_FIXTURES, UPDATE_PREDICTIONS } = predictFormSlice.actions;

export default predictFormSlice.reducer;
```

It would be nice to just update the key for the **awayTeamScore** and **homeTeamScore** by using the **matchId**, inside the reducer. My action is sending the payload successfully to the **UPDATE_PREDICTION** reducer, just not updating the state, I was just trying to completely replace the object first before just focusing on certain keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things here:

- you are confusing *modifying an object* and *reassigning a variable*. You can do `variableName.foo = 5` and it will change the property `foo` of `variableName` to `5`. But if instead you would do `let foo = variableName.foo; foo = 5`, you would assign the value `5` to the variable `foo`, but there would not be a connection to `variableName` any more - `variableName` would not change. You are doing this with both `state` and `game` here: you reassign both variables, but you "change" nothing.
- you create a full new array with `.map` - you don't need to do that in an immer reducer.

This would go about this in a "object-modifying" approach instead of reassigning things.

```js
        UPDATE_PREDICTIONS: (state: any, action) => {
            for (const element of state[0]) {
                let idx = element.findIndex((game: { matchId: any }) => game.matchId === action.payload.matchId);

                if (idx >= 0) {
                    element[idx] = action.payload;
                }
            };
        },
```

Comment: great! and for modifying specific keys in the object I did this:  if (idx >= 0) {
     element[idx][action.payload.team] = action.payload.score;
    }